# Firebase storage deletes files automatically

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I stumbled uppon an issue that has been bothering me for some time now. I'm developing an app with firebase (cloud functions, firestore and firestorage) and have noticed, that the files stored in the firebase bucket get deleted after some arbitrary amount of time. I have been reading about the buckets lifecycle and even tried to adjust it, with no result. The files still get deleted automatically after a couple of hours. There are no logs, nothing. I am very confused at this point, because I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Anyone else that has had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't have any functionality for automatically deleting files after a while, but Cloud Storage (which the Firebase SDKs wrap) has the opportunity to [configure a lifecycle](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) for the objects in its buckets. Did you, or a collaborator on the project, configure that by any chance?

Comment: That's the thing, we didn't. I also have looked at the lifecycle rules and added the object retention to be at least 30 days, but it seems to be ignored even after the 24h window it takes for the changes to take place. I even tried to create a new, fresh bucket, hoping it would solve the problem, but it did not. Any suggestion to what I can do in this situation?

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that I'm making the objects public for user to access. The deafult cache for public objects is 3600s https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/caching#:~:text=Built%2Din%20caching%20for%20Cloud%20Storage,-Cloud%20Storage%20behaves&text=By%20default%2C%20the%20max%2Dage,3600%20seconds%20(1%20hour). which would explain why they do not exist after that time. What is strange however is that they actually are deleted from the bucket and not from a cache. Could that be the issue?

Comment: The caching interview should not result the source object being deleted, but I definitely haven't used that part of Cloud Storage.